# Warning of dead code in else statement within a try - catch

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
try {
    if ((jsonData = new JSONObject(getJSONString(request))) != null) {
        if (jsonData.has("country_code")) {
            user_id = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("user_id"));
            jobjcountries = new OpenNCPApi().getCountryListAttritube(jsonData.getString("country_code"), "en");
            jObj.put("status", 1);
            jObj.put("attributes", jobjcountries);
            return jObj.toString();
        } else {
            jObj.put("status", 0);
            jObj.put("error", "Unfilled inputs");
            return jObj.toString();
        }
    }
    //request is null
    else {
        jObj.put("status", 0);
        jObj.put("error", "Unfilled inputs");
        return jObj.toString();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    jObj.put("status", 0);
    jObj.put("error", "Problem while calling ncp service");
    return jObj.toString();
} finally {...}
```

For the following code I get a warning of `dead code`.

```
   else {
            jObj.put("status", 0);
            jObj.put("error", "Unfilled inputs");
            return jObj.toString();
        }
```

However, `return jObj.toString();` is needed to be there and I need to have `status` and `error` values. I've added this `else` statement to satisfies the case when `(jsonData = new JSONObject(getJSONString(request)))` is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing that `((jsonData = new JSONObject(getJSONString(request))) != null)` never will be `null` as you create a new object reference. The value of the object could be null. But in that case, the `else{}` statement will not be reached and can safely be deleted.

Comment: When creating a new Object, you normally have an Object-Constructor with Parameters. Those could be null.

Answer (score 1):

> I've added this else statement to satisfies the case when (jsonData =
> new JSONObject(getJSONString(request))) is null.

The `new JSONObject(getJSONString(request)))` will never be `null`. As one can conclude by reading [JLS section 15.9.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.4):

> **The value of a class instance creation expression is a reference to
> the newly created object of the specified class.** Every time the
> expression is evaluated, a fresh object is created.

This statement

`(jsonData = new JSONObject(getJSONString(request))) != null)`

will either evaluate to `true` or throw an `Exception`.

If it evaluate to `true` then one of the following branches will be executed:

```
if (jsonData.has("country_code")) {
    user_id = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("user_id"));
    jobjcountries = new OpenNCPApi().getCountryListAttritube(jsonData.getString("country_code"), "en");
    jObj.put("status", 1);
    jObj.put("attributes", jobjcountries);
    return jObj.toString();
    
} else {
    jObj.put("status", 0);
    jObj.put("error", "Unfilled inputs");
    return jObj.toString();
}
```

If it throws an exception then:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    jObj.put("status", 0);
    jObj.put("error", "Problem while calling ncp service");
    return jObj.toString();
```

will be executed.

In either the aforementioned cases the block:

```
else {
    jObj.put("status", 0);
    jObj.put("error", "Unfilled inputs");
    return jObj.toString();
}
```

will never be reach, hence the warning about dead code.